# C# рекурсивный поиск с исключением

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! Нужен примерный код, который делал поиск во всех папка, кроме определенных, то есть например сканирую диск **C:/**. И в нем надо исключить папку **C:/Windows** то есть, чтобы он исключил эту папку и пошел по следующей, например по **C:/Games**, но не по самой **C:/Windows**.

Вот мой код

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path, string pattern)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> files = null;
        try { files = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern); }
        catch { }

        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (var file in files) yield return file;
        }

        IEnumerable<string> directories = null;
        try { directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path); }
        catch { }

        if (directories != null)
        {
            foreach (var file in directories.SelectMany(d => GetFiles(d, pattern)))
            {
                yield return file;
            }
        }
    }


    public void DirSearch(string sDir, string keywords)
    {
        List<string> DirList = new List<string>();
        DirList.Add("C:\\Windows");

        var s1 = FileSearch.GetFiles(sDir, "*.ini").Where(d => DirList.All(e => !d.StartsWith(e)));
        foreach (string file in s1)
        {
            if (FindKeywords(file, keywords)) // тут мой код, думаю не обязательно показывать
            {
                MessageBox.Show(file);
            }
        }
    }
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: И что, ваш код не работает?

Comment: Он та работает, только он продолжает искать в C:/Windows
А мне надо, чтобы он пропустил эту папку вообще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно фильтровать список директорий непосредственно в процессе обхода (переменная `directories` в методе `GetFiles()`), а постфактум не список файлов (в методе `DirSearch()`).

Как-нибудь так:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path, string pattern, Predicate<string> excludeDirectory)
{
    ...

    if (directories != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in directories.Where(d => !excludeDirectory(d)).SelectMany(d => GetFiles(d, pattern, excludeDirectory)))
        {
            yield return file;
        }
    }
}

public void DirSearch(string sDir, string keywords)
{
    List<string> DirList = new List<string>();
    DirList.Add("C:\\Windows");

    var s1 = FileSearch.GetFiles(sDir, "*.ini", DirList.Contains);
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Можно пример, если не сложно

Comment: @HackMemory обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: @HackMemory не за что!

Comment: @andreycha, А как без Linq сделать?

Comment: @Luser вместо `Where` используйте `if`, а вместо `SelectMany` -- вложенный `foreach`.