# C# и методы получения списка файлов

Tags: c#, .net

В C# есть методы для получения списка файлов, которым можно подать на вход параметр SearchOption.AllDirectories.

Подскажите, а можно ли как-нибудь избежать возникающие исключения(Проигнорировать)?

Например, программа попытается заглянуть в системную папку, где отсутствует доступ.

**UPD**

Мой вопрос не совсем дубль.

Тот вопрос на который предоставлена ссылка описывает, как игнорировать некоторые папки при рекурсивном обходе.

Мой вопрос про то, что можно ли используя SearchOption.AllDirectories и корень диска C проигнорировать все исключения и вернуть список файлов.

Comment: `try { ... } catch { ... }`?

Comment: @Mirdin, если не ошибаюсь, то не сработает. Так как результатом метода GetFiles является коллекция=> если внутри происходит исключение, то мне ничего не возвращается, а хотелось бы, что бы возвращалось. Получается, что только ручками обходить?

Comment: ну так не запрашивайте AllDirectories на корне диска, либо сделайте рекурсивную функцию, в нем не нуждающуюся (здесь где то был подобный вопрос)

Comment: В этом уроке есть нужный вам код -- самостоятельный обход с обработкой исключений: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554087/106

Comment: _Мой вопрос про то, что можно ли используя SearchOption.AllDirectories и корень диска C проигнорировать все исключения и вернуть список файлов._ - нет нельзя